# How to create a modal window and load HTML from render process?

Tags: modal-dialog, electron

this is my current project structure:

```
main.js
index.html
download.html
src/index.js
src/style.css
```

`main.js` will create a BrowserWindow and load `index.html`, which loads `index.js` and `style.css`.

I'd like to create a new modal window and load `download.html` when a button is clicked in `index.html`.

here is codes from my `index.js`:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  let win = new remote.BrowserWindow({
    parent: remote.getCurrentWindow(),
    modal: true
  })
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/download.html`)
}
```

but it's loading `file://download.html`, isn't `__dirname` existed in render process?

Comment: what happens with: `console.log( __dirname);`?

Comment: @NoGrabbing it outputs `/`

Comment: If @NoGrabbing answered your question, please be sure to mark it the answer. That solution worked great for me.

Answer (score 13):

Just tested this code (below) and it works. Directory structure is:

> main.js
>   app (directory)
>   --- index.html
>   --- app.js (where the code below exists)
>   --- modal.html

How are you accessing `remote`?

---

```
"use strict";

const { remote } = require('electron');


function openModal() {
  let win = new remote.BrowserWindow({
    parent: remote.getCurrentWindow(),
    modal: true
  })

  var theUrl = 'file://' + __dirname + '/modal.html'
  console.log('url', theUrl);

  win.loadURL(theUrl);
}
```

Comment: I'm accessing `remote` just like you

Comment: @wong2 – what are the $ and curly braces for? `${__dirname}` – is that a jquery + react thing?

Comment: that's _String Interpolation_ a ES6 feature

Comment: So many other methods make this out to be so complicated. Holy crap is this easy. Thank you.

Comment: How can they communicate via ipcRenderer? I can't make the messages work.

Comment: what is the purpose of a modal in electron? it looks like the modal was loaded normally into the application as if the application had loaded `index.html`?

Comment: A `modal` in Electron is a separate app **window** - not a `div` like in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Using `__dirname` will give the directory of the current file. In the main process it will be according to the filesystem. In a renderer process it will be in the context of the browser and be based on the accessed uri.

You likely want to use [`app.getAppPath`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetapppath) or [`app.getPath(name)`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetpathname) instead.